# Java Deployment, what exactly is it?

Tags: java, deployment

I have developed a simple Java application as an assignment. There is a next step to this assignment, which I do not understand clearly.

- Develop a script to deploy both client and server in automated way

When you say "develop a script to deploy" in Java, does it mean to create a script that builds executable .jar file from your package? Or does it mean to actually have my application somewhere in the web so everyone can access it? What exactly does automated deployment mean in general when it comes to Java?

Comment: You should ask your instructor what he means.

Comment: There is no instructor for this- I just want to know what this means in general as I do not have much knowledge in script and deployment

Comment: You referred to this as an "assignment".  You should ask the person who assigned you this task.  There are many possible meanings to "deployment" so we need more info.

Comment: I would think it means that you're supposed to write installer `.bat`, `.sh`, .. command line scripts (not in java). The goal of "deploy" is that it can be run by some user, the question is from which state that should happen.. based on a downloaded .jar or source repository, ...

Answer (score 1):

As per my experience in the java field automated deployment means your code is compiled from a repository and built into a jar war ear at a certain location and this is done automatically through tools like ant maven Hudson etc so here ant and maven are helping you build the artifacts like the jar war etc and Hudson helps in scheduling the time for the build and the location where the artifacts need to be stored etc. the advantage of automation lies in the removal of manual intervention

Comment: Thank you- I got an idea of what I should do. I think I can accomplish it by using Ant

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the nature of the application.  To 'deploy both client and server' in an automated way depends on what's being deployed.

Client/server is quite vague.  Can you be more specific on what the application does?
How would you deploy it manually?